# SharePoint Document Library Column Advice Needed for a Multiple Value Field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created a basic OOTB document library to store Word and PDF files. I have been tasked to also create a few columns to store some basic metadata about the uploaded documents, for example: AuthorFirstName, AuthorLastName, and a column that lists "topics" discussed in the document.

While I am generally familiar with most Document Library settings, and creating columns, I am seeking information on what column datatype might work best for "topics". In most situations, one uploaded document would have 1-4 topics.

I would rather the datatype not be a `single line of text` datatype, as I would rather not ask the user to separate the different values (topics) using a delimiter such as a comma or semicolon. I would like to offer users the option to sort or filter in the SharePoint views.

There also seem to be some limitations with the `Choice` datatype. 
While `Choice` fields seem to support Fill-In Values, when a choice is not pre-populated, they only seem to allow 1 fill-in. I would like the user to able to use a repeating-table-like interface to add a topic, and click an "add" button, and repeat, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your scenario the best approach would be using managed metadata feature (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/introduction-to-managed-metadata-HA102832521.aspx). It allows you to sort/filter library items, allows users to add new terms into metadata storage, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Lookup field to a custom List is something worth considering.  The main advantage is that your data choices are stored separately from the main list and are easier to track and manage.  The disadvantage is that you cannot easily have the user add a fill-in option as you desire.  You would have to have a link from the library or the upload form to the options list where they would enter a new option separately from tagging it on the document.

Managed metadata is certainly an option as well, but it requires more overhead and sorting/filtering on that is a little trickier.  Using a Lookup column is simple, although it does not meet all of your needs.